# angular-ui-swiper - How to set options?

Tags: angularjs, swiper.js

I am trying to use angular-ui-swiper with AngularJS. Implementation was very easy, please see here https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ui-swiper

But I am not able to set more options for this slider, because I found no angular examples on the web.  Can you please support me?

I am able to access the instance of the slider via "instance"-Attribute set in the html code. But I just managed to jump to a special slide. But I also want to have initially 3 slides per view for example. How can I achieve this?

Thank you

```
   <swiper  instance="instance">
                    <slides>
                        <slide  ng-repeat="subpage in sliderElements">
                            <img src="{{subpage.featuredImage}}" alt="" title=""/>
                        </slide>
                    </slides>
                    <prev></prev>
                    <next></next>
                    <pagination></pagination>
                </swiper>
```

Here are some options I need:

```
<script>
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  slidesPerView: 4,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  centeredSlides: true,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
});
```

https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/130-centered.html

Comment: I actually solved this issue by my own. On this site you can find a whole overview over all config params. https://github.com/nebulr/ui-swiper/blob/master/dist/angular-ui-swiper.js#L22 If you need to set an param then you have to do this directly in the swiper-tag. The words are seperated with a "dash" . So for "SlidesPerView" you add the html-attribute "slides-per-view"  in the swiper-tag

Answer (score 1):

You should write each property in this form (add -):
`<swiper slides-per-view="4">` this is the same like slidesPerView: 4